# Python Pandas keyError when passing a column list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe that has 4 columns `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. and I want to check if columns `A` and `B` have duplicate records.

```
column_list=['A','B']

#I tried:
output_df=df[df.duplicated(column_list)]

#and: 
output_df=df[df.duplicated(subset=column_list)]

#and:
output_df=df[df.duplicated(subset=[column_list])]
```

All give me the same error: `[ERROR] KeyError: Index(['['A','B']'], dtype='object')`. I have double checked that the column names matches the list of variables I passed - spelling and case.

Comment: Based on the error's message, you're using a literal string `column_list= "['A', 'B']"` and not a list `column_list= ['A', 'B']`. If not, you have to prove it with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Please post a full script demonstrating the error.

Comment: Have you tried setting `column_list` like this : `column_list = [["A", "B"]]`?

Comment: @Timeless You're right, what I passed is a string, not a list. This is an aws lambda function variable. I thought it would honor the list format. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You sure that all 3 options are invalid? First two ones seems legit (if I tested correctly).

Third one may be the reason. When you wrap column_list inside another list `([column_list])`, it's interpreted as a list of lists, which is not what you intend. This causes pandas to look for a column named `['A', 'B']` as a single entity, which doesn't exist in your DataFrame, leading to the KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need to index the `df`, but can simply
do:

```py
output_df = df.duplicated(subset=column_list)
```

to return `True` or `False` for each record whether it is a duplicate or not.

Additionally, this:

```py
df_without_duplicates = df.drop_duplicates(subset=column_list)
```

will return a DataFrame without any of the duplicates in `df`.